# AWK - Match first column, print both lines if any values of the last field is greater than 1000

Tags: awk

I'm having difficulties multiple lines as one.  I hope getting this question resolved will help me with the next tasks I'll need to perform.

**Logic**

If the first columns match, check if any of the line's last field is greater than or equal to 1000.  If it is, print all lines.

**Current Code:**

I've tried I basic code but I know it's failing because I'm not grouping the matching lines.

```
awk -F' ' '$1==$1 {print $0}' file | awk -v X=1000 -F' ' '{if($NF >= X)print $0}'
```

**File**

```
LSP0    NODE0   NODE4   NODE3   591
LSP0    NODE0   NODE4   NODE5   NODE3   515
LSP1    NODE2   NODE4   NODE3   NODE6   5511
LSP1    NODE2   NODE1   551
LSP2    NODE4   NODE5   NODE7   60714
LSP2    NODE1   1501
```

**Desired Output**

```
LSP1    NODE2   NODE4   NODE3   NODE6   5511
LSP1    NODE2   NODE1   551
LSP2    NODE4   NODE5   NODE7   60714
LSP2    NODE1   1501
```

**Possible?**

If the first column matches, sum the last field.  Resort all lines using the sum of the matching lines.

```
LSP2    NODE4   NODE5   NODE7   60714
LSP2    NODE1   1501
LSP1    NODE2   NODE4   NODE3   NODE6   5511
LSP1    NODE2   NODE1   551
```

Comment: I couldn't understand why do your "desired" output and the last output look the same except for swapped groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gawk '
    {lines[$1] = lines[$1] $0 ORS; sum[$1] += $NF} 
    $NF > 1000 {p[$1] = 1} 
    END {
        PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"
        for (key in sum) 
            if (p[key])
                printf "%s", lines[key]
    }
' file
```

Comment: This one summed up the values as opposed to sorting the two rows, then resorting based on the top row.  Thanks

Comment: If that's not what you want, then you'll need to elaborate on "Resort all lines using the sum of the matching lines"

Answer (score 1):

a double scan algorithm

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]+=($NF>=1000); next} a[$1]' file{,}

LSP1    NODE2   NODE4   NODE3   NODE6   5511
LSP1    NODE2   NODE1   551
LSP2    NODE4   NODE5   NODE7   60714
LSP2    NODE1   1501
```

mark the keys where the criteria matches in the first scan, and print filtered rows in the second time.

Here is the sorted variation

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]+=($NF>=1000)?$NF:0; next} 
       a[$1]   {print a[$1] "\t" $0}' file{,} | sort -s -k1nr | cut -f2-

LSP2    NODE4   NODE5   NODE7   60714
LSP2    NODE1   1501
LSP1    NODE2   NODE4   NODE3   NODE6   5511
LSP1    NODE2   NODE1   551
```

assumes values are positive (so that don't summed up to zero, which will filter them out).